# I Want The Current Setting Not To Change When Browser Refresh Is Made By Adding Cookie Codes In The Script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I placed the following script code into the night mode button with the help of **onclick = "swap ()"**. My goal: When the page is in dark mode, the other logo is active. When it's daytime mode, get another logo. But the problem is that when I do F5 on the page while in dark mode, the logo reverts to its original state even though the page remains in dark mode. Is it possible to edit the script code to help it stay in the cache in the browser?

```js
var shown = 'header_logo_ayar_1';

function swap() {
  if (shown === 'header_logo_ayar_1') {
    document.getElementById('header_logo_2').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('header_logo_1').style.display = "none";
    shown = 'header_logo_ayar_2';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('header_logo_1').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('header_logo_2').style.display = "none";
    shown = 'header_logo_ayar_1';
  }
};
```

```html
<a id="header_logo_1" href="#" title="">
  <figure><img src="img/logo_1.webp" alt="" width="" height=""></figure>
</a>
<a id="header_logo_2" href="#" title="" style="display:none;">
  <figure><img src="img/logo_2.webp" alt="" width="" height=""></figure>
</a>
```

I got this working example from here: https://jsfiddle.net/v2k3rzge/

I edited my own work.

If there are friends who can help on the subject, I ask them to answer. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: you could put the choosen theme into localStorage. Then when the page loads you check if there is a theme in the storage and ifs o you use that, if not use use the default. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to get and set items.

```js
var shown;
if (localStorage.getItem("shown") === null) {
  shown = "header_logo_ayar_1";
} else {
  shown = localStorage.getItem("shown");
}
// Or you could do this (with more advanced syntax)
var shown = (localStorage.getItem("shown") ?? "header_logo_ayar_1");


function swap() {
  // ...

  localStorage.setItem("shown", shown);
}
```

`localStorage` doesn't work in Stack Snippets, so try [this JSitor link](https://jsitor.com/05IqTc7sTP).

Comment: By the way, this assumes you want the default value to be `"header_logo_ayar_1"`

Comment: thank you for your help but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: huh... One problem could be the `shown` variable is not defined in the right scope. Do you have any console errors?

Comment: I couldn't see any console errors. I tried the script code on another non-night mode script. I made a small button and added onclick = "swap ()". When I click the button, the function works, but when I do F5, it returns to its original state. does not become permanent. :)

Comment: I'm trying the script codes on jsitor.com right now, I've just seen them. Thank you.